# How can I use application.properties of child gradle module?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, properties, configuration

I have project structure like like this.

```
     parent
     |   |         |
 child1  child2  child3 ....
      |   |
     common
```

In `common` project I want to extract all common things for `child1` and `child2`

I want to extract common properties to `application.properties` of common project

But after extracting common properties if in child project I write comething like:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoDataConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;
```

It could not find property in `application.properties` of common project:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.data.mongodb.database' in value "${spring.data.mongodb.database}"
```

How can I achieve it?

### P.S.

parent `settings.gradle`:

```
include 'child1'
include 'child2'
include 'child3'
...
```

In each child `build.gradle`:

```
compile project(':common')
```

### P.P.S.

It is working if rename file in common projects to commons.properties and write:

```
 @PropertySource("classpath:commons.properties")
```

But it would be better to have `application.properties` name.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you include the common-project into child1, child2, you just use the annotation `@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")` that would search properties in child1's application.properties.So if you want to get the properties in common-project, you should provide a method to get those properties in your common-project.

Comment: Do you know how to invoke this method? which method?